# Complex Analysis: Picard's theorem applying to cot(z)

Tags: complex-analysis

Why doesn't Picard's Theorem apply to $cot(z)$? Under my understanding, $cot(z)$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$, because there is no punctured neighborhood of $0$ in which $cot(1/z)$ is bounded. Since $cot(z)$ has this singularity, Picard's Thm implies it assumes all but possibly 1 complex value. However, there is no $z$ for which $cot(z) = i$, and no $z$ for which $cot(z) = -i$. This is seemingly a contradiction. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $\cot$ is meromorphic (has poles), not entire and $\infty$ is a limit of poles so the singularity is not isolated; whether you call such essential or not is a matter of taste/opinion etc but Picard applies to isolated singularities not to such; incidentally (little) Picard still applies as it states that a meromorphic function in the plane cannot omit three values - for entire fucntions, $\infty$ is automatically omitted hence the usual statement there, but again $\cot$ being meromorphic takes $\infty$ so can (and does) omit two finite values

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much. I didn't realize it had to be isolated.

Comment: see the complete comment - little Picard still applies, just that now $\cot$ takes infinity so can omit two finite values; an entire function omits infinity so can omit only one finite value

Comment: Oh wow that's an incredible insight into the problem, I never knew Picard acted like that. Thank you so much, that's amazing!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in a comment by Conrad, the singularity at $\infty$ is essential but not isolated, and Picard only applies to isolated.